# Pytest mock pandas read_excel inside the Class Construction

Tags: python, pandas, pytest, pytest-mock

I am doing some Integration tests using Pytest. I am reading my excel sheet input from the class constructor. I don't know how to mock the read_excel function of pandas.
My actual code,

```
import pandas as pd

class Sample:
    def __init__(self, input_file_path):
        self.df_input = pd.read_excel(
                        input_file_path, sheet_name="Input sheet", header=[0]
                )
        
    def calculation(self):
        pass
    def choose_template(self):
        pass
    

sample_obj = Sample('./test.xlsx')
sample_obj.choose_template()
```

test_one.py,

```
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"DB_CONNECTION_STRING": "Mock_Connection_String", 
                              "DB_DATABASE": "Mock_Db", 
                              "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING": "Mock_Azure_connection_String", 
                              },clear=True)



def test_choose_template_valid():
    expected = "fizz"
    sample_obj = Sample('./test.xlsx')

    sample_obj.choose_template()
    actual = "fizz"
    assert actual == expected
```

I am getting the following error. I understand why this is happening. But I need a solution on how to mockup the `pd.read_excel` call.

```
=============================================================== short test summary info ================================================================
FAILED test_report.py::test_choose_template_valid - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './test.xlsx'
================================================================== 1 failed in 0.96s ===================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that your code is already executed on importing your module. In this case you cannot mock it before it is called.

Call that code after the usual `if __name__ == "__main__"`  check, or better yet, move into a function, and call that function after the check:

```py
class Sample:
  ...

def choose_sample_template(file_name):
    sample_obj = Sample(file_name)
    return sample_obj.choose_template()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    choose_sample_template('./test.xlsx')
```

Now you can mock `pd.read_excel` the usual way while testing that function:

```py
@mock.patch.dict(...)
@mock.patch("your_module.pd.read_excel")
def test_choose_template_valid(mocked_read):
    mocked_read.return_value = ... # some df
    expected = "fizz"   
    actual = choose_sample_template('./test.xlsx')
    assert actual == expected
```

with `your_module` being the module where `Sample` is defined.

If you have more than one subsequent call to `pd.read_excel` in your tested call, as mentioned in the comments, you can use `side_effect` instead of `return_value`:

```py
@mock.patch.dict(...)
@mock.patch("your_module.pd.read_excel")
def test_choose_template_valid(mocked_read):
    mocked_read.side_effect = [
       some_df,
       second_df,
       third_df
    ]
    ...
```

Comment: I am reading multiple sheets in the same constructor functions. I don't know how to mock them too. and also, what should I give 'your_module'? Because I am reading excel sheets inside the constructor function.

Comment: I adapted the answer.